# удаление товаров из корзины с помощью JQuery.post()

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <script
        src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
        integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
        crossorigin="anonymous">
   </script>
   <title>Document</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="catalog.css"/>
</head>
<body>

  <?php if(!empty($cart)):?>
      <a href="catalog.php">go to catalog</a>
  <?php endif;?>

  <?php if(!empty($cart)):?>
    <table>
           <?php foreach($cart as $key=>$val):?>
                <?php $count++;?>

        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $count;?></td>
            <td ><img class="cart_img"  src="<?php echo IMG_PATH.$val['product_img'];?>"></td>
            <td ><?php echo isset($error[$val['product_name']])?'Осталось '.$error[$val['product_name']]:$val['product_quantity'];?></td>
            <td>price</td>
            <td><?php echo $num[$val['product_name']];?></td>
            <td>total</td>
            <td>
             <form method="post">   
                <input type="button" id="del" name="del[<?php echo $val['product_name']; ?>]" onclick="f()" value="Delete from cart">
             </form>
             </td>
        </tr>

           <?php endforeach;?>             
    </table> 
 <?php else:?>
    <h1>Your cart is empty!</h1>
    <h2><a href="catalog.php">go to shopping</a></h2>
 <?php endif;?>
 <script>


       function f(){
           var id=$(this).attr("name");
           alert(id);
           $.post(
                  "cart.php",
                   id,
                  );

       };

    </script>
```

Подскажите как в jquery скрипте правильно распознать атрибут нажатой кнопки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Убрать у кнопок `id="del"`, т.к. у Вас на странице, наверное, будет много таких кнопок. А много элементов на странице с одним id - это плохо. Возникнут проблемы с работой.
2. Убрать у кнопок `onclick="f()"` и добавить какой-нибудь уникальный класс (например, `delete-from-cart-btn`) или дата-атрибут (допустим, `data-role`) для дальнейшего навешивания на него слушателя событий.
3. Повесить на кнопки слушатели событий. Например:

   ```
   $('.delete-from-cart-btn').on('click', function() {
     var id = $(this).attr("name");
     alert(id); // выведет на экран нужный Вам ID
   });
   ```

Comment: Спасибо огромное) Если не затруднит подскажите почему не работал вариант когда id формировался динамически `<input id="<?php echo $val['product_name']; ?>" type="button"  name="del[<?php echo $val['product_name']; ?>]" value="Delete from cart">`  jquery скрипт был тот же и у меня всегда выбирался первый элемент??

Comment: В том варианте у Вас в коде на странице присутствовало `onclick="f()"` это значит что когда Вы кликали по кнопке и переходили в функцию `f()` внутри неё указатель `$(this)` содержал не элемент по которому кликнули, а саму функцию (возможно я грубо и неправильно объяснил, если интересно просто погуглите) ), а через слушатель `.. on('click' ..` через указатель `$(this)` Вы как раз таки получаете объект по которому кликнули

Comment: Вроде понял,до этого код был таким только селектор был не this, а id) вот теперь я отправляю всё это дело таким образом `$(document).ready(
                   $('.delete-from-cart-btn').on('click', function() {
                         var id=$(this).attr("name");
                            alert(id); // выведет на экран нужный Вам ID
                            $.post( "cart.php","id="+id, function(data){alert(data);}
                )} ));` <br> почему data-это вся страница?

Comment: "почему data-это вся страница?". Этот вопрос нужно задать файлу cart.php. посмотрите что в нём возвращается. Возможно там и возвращается вся страница а не то что Вам нужно.

Comment: (https://pastebin.com/E8pdGECs )визуально там все в порядке или я не вижу. Основной вопрос в том как теперь удалить элемент без перезагрузки?php код я написал, но он отрабатывает после перезагрузки, а jquery  пока не владею(

Comment: Нужно наверное вставить в код callback функцию которая будет принимать ответ из файла cart.php и делать с данными на странице что-то. Посмотрите здесь http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/Ajax_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC_POST

Comment: Благодаря Вам я это понял! но видимо из-за того, что сервер по непонятным мне причинам возвращает всю страницу, сделать это не удается, попытался сделать так `$(document).ready(
                   $('.delete-from-cart-btn').on('click', function() {
                         var id=$(this).attr("name");
                            $.post("cart.php", "id="+id,function(data){
                                 $(data).children("#id").remove();
                             }
                )}
            ));`

Comment: получилось с так `$(document).ready(
                   $('.delete-from-cart-btn').on('click', function() {
                         var id=$(this).attr("name");
                             $.post( "cart.php", "id="+id, function(data){
                                    $("body").html(data);
                                                              }  )} ));` Вопрос на сколько это правильно?

Comment: вот здесь не знаю. я сам больше по php. по идее из файла cart.php должен возвращаться массив или json или что-то ещё. то есть должна присутствовать допустим такая строка в конце `return $array;` тогда аяксом на страницу будет возвращаться только этот массив и на его основе можно будет javascript-ом вывести на экран то что нужно. Но как говорится "работает - не трогай" и если ваш метод срабатывает то всё отлично

Comment: да напрягает ,что получается вложенная страница в body!визуально конечно не видно, но неграмотно(( Спасибо Вам за помощь!)